# Combinatronics Summation Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I have a series as follows:

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{15} {30 \choose 2k-1}/2k$$

I have tried expanding and evaluating by replacing $${30\choose29}/30 $$ with $${30\choose1}/30 $$

How do you solve it, is there a general approach to attempt such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k=1}^{15}\binom{30}{2k-1}\frac{1}{2k}}&=\frac{1}{31}\sum_{k=1}^{15}\binom{31}{2k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{31}\sum_{k=1}^{15}\binom{31}{32-2k}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{31}\sum_{k=1}^{15}\binom{31}{2k-1}\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{31}\left(2^{30}-1\right)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (2) we  change the  order of summation $k\rightarrow15-k+1=16-k$.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (4) we observe  that the series in (1)  and  (3) summed up give
  $\sum_{k=1}^{30}\binom{31}{k}=2^{31}-2$.

Comment: Excellent answer. Any idea how this can strike mind during exams?

Comment: @user5722540: Thanks for your nice comment. Crucial (as usual) is training and experience. I recommend a thorough study of chapter 5 *Binomial Coefficients* of *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik. The tables there are of great help and learning from this book was (is) great fun for me.

Comment: You have no idea, how helpful this answer was for me. Will surely read the book.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac1{2k}=\int_0^1x^{2k-1}\,dx.$$
Your sum is
$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{k=1}^{15}\binom{30}{2k-1}x^{2k-1}\right)\,dx.$$
Now
$$\sum_{k=1}^{15}\binom{30}{2k-1}x^{2k-1}$$
is the sum of the terms with odd powers of $x$ in
$$\sum_{j=0}^{30}\binom{30}{j}x^{j}$$
and there's a standard trick to extracting the "odd part" of a polynomial
or power series...

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, please explain your first step.

Comment: got your first step, wow never thought integration for binomial series

Comment: "and there's a standard trick to extracting the "odd part" of a polynomial or power series..."... can you share the link

Comment: Got it! thanks!